# How to raise an error in AWS Lambda handler

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I call two classes in my AWS Lambda handler, which are not related with each other. Because I need to setup the same cron job scheduler both are in the same lambda handler.

I want to display an error if one fails but in the same time the second call of class should work:

```
def handle(event:, context:)
  ListCreator.new.call
  Messenger.new.call
  { statusCode: 200 }
end
```

`ListCreator.new.call` got nil,   raised an error `'I was not able to send a message'`,   `Messenger.new.call`,   200

And the same when Messenger failed.

How do I do that?

Comment: You want to raise an error and yet still return `{ statusCode: 200 }`?

Comment: Yup - error to one of the class if it fails. Is this a bad practice? If I leave it like it is, it will be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ensure`:

```
def handle(event:, context:)
  ListCreator.new.call
rescue SomeErrorTypeFromListCreator => e # or just rescue => e 
  'I was not able to send a message'
ensure
  begin
    Messenger.new.call
    { statusCode: 200 }
  rescue SomeErrorTypeFromMessenger => e # or just rescue => e 
    'I was not able to send the other message'
  end
end
```

The [`ensure`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/ensure.html) block will be called every time.

I don't think you can raise both things at the same time, maybe you can return those strings or log them.

Comment: Please don't use "edit" or "updated" type tags in answers or questions. Instead incorporate the new information into the text as if it'd always been there. Readability and making sense are more important than showing a flow of changes, which is automatically handled by SO's revision control and is visible to us.